# ffmpeg output stereoscopic by duplicating a single input

Tags: ffmpeg, x11, virtual-reality, stereoscopy

I want to have my desktop output video to be used with a VR headset so I need to convert the X11 output to left and right eye (but as a single video), it won't be 3D since the left and right eye input is the same but thats fine.  I think I am almost there but can't get ffmpeg to treat a single source as two inputs. Here is what I have so far>

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60  -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -i :0.0  -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=iw/2:ih/2, pad=2*iw:ih [left]; [1:v] scale=iw/3:ih/3, fade=out:300:30:alpha=1 [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -vcodec libx264 -crf 16 -preset ultrafast sidebyside.mp4
```

The command above should create a single output video with a duplicate of my display input for left and right eye on the left and right part of the video.

The ffmpeg command above fails with

> :0.0: Protocol not found
>   Did you mean file::0.0?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `-f x11grab -framerate 60  -video_size 1920x1080` needs to be inserted before the 2nd input as well. But this should be carried out in a different way, to maintain sync

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60  -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[l][r];[l]scale=iw/2:ih/2, pad=2*iw:ih [left]; [r] scale=iw/3:ih/3, fade=out:300:30:alpha=1 [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -vcodec libx264 -crf 16 -preset ultrafast sidebyside.mp4`

(You're scaling the right side to smaller dimensions but I assume that's intended)

Comment: fixed the right side dimentions error I think but it is still not working with > ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60  -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -filter_complex "[0:v]split=2p[l][r];[l]scale=iw/2:ih/2, pad=2*iw:ih [left]; [r] scale=iw/2:ih/2, fade=out:300:30:alpha=1 [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -vcodec libx264 -crf 16 -preset ultrafast sidebyside.mp4

Comment: produces error>  [split @ 0x55a6ad804180] Value 0.000000 for parameter 'outputs' out of range [1 - 2.14748e+09]
    Last message repeated 1 times
[split @ 0x55a6ad804180] Error setting option outputs to value 2p.
[Parsed_split_0 @ 0x55a6ad806340] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55a6ad805480] Error initializing filter 'split' with args '2p'
Error initializing complex filters.
Numerical result out of range

Comment: Corrected typo.